# Trivial questions/examples about derivatives in higher dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I am just learning to work with derivatives in higher dimensions. I am struggling to catch up in my new math class and I don't know where to start in tackling the following problems. A worked example would help greatly, as the resources I have are all generalized, and this hasn't been sufficient to help me understand.

1) Let $g : R^3 -> R$ be such that $g(0) = 2$ and $[Dg(0)] = [1 \ 1 \ 1]. Find $D(1/g)(0)$.

Solution: Given $[Dg(0)] = [1 \ 1 \ 1]$, would we not have that $g(0) = (x, y, z)$? Then $D(1/g)(0) = [-1 /x^2, -1/y^2, -1/z^2] ?

2) Let $f(x) : R -> R^2, f(x) = (f_1(x), f_2(x))$. Given that $f_1, f_2$ are differentiable, find $[Df(x_0)]$ in terms of $f'_1(x_0), f'_2(x_0)$.

I don't know how to start on this one. What do we really know about $f$? Won't the answer simply be $[f'_1(x_0), f'_2(x_0)]$?

Thank you

Comment: Hint for #1: use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, note that $g$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$, so $g(0)$ can't be $(x,y,z)$--that is a vector on $\mathbb{R}^3$! In fact you have $g(0)=2$, so $(1/g)(0)=1/2$. To find the derivative of $1/g$ at zero, you should remember how to relate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g$ to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(1/g)$ (just like in the one-variable case).

Another option for #1 is to use the chain rule, as amd suggests.

For #2, you should include how you have defined $[Df(x_0)]$, and then you can try to relate that to the partial derivatives.

Comment: so for #1 we would have [-4 -4 -4], correct?